# LibreOffice Maven Dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, libreoffice

I am trying to run LibreOffice's [examples](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/DevelopersGuide/examples.html) in a small Maven project. Netbeans does not seem to find dependencies in Maven.

For example:

```
import com.sun.star.awt.Point;
```

It seems hard to believe that LibreOffice's dependencies are not available in Maven. Or aren't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not..

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/star

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.star%22

Arguably that should be fixed. I would suggest to raise an issue with LibreOffice and in the mean time install your own repository server like Sonatype Nexus and deploy the needed jars there.

Comment: There is a ticket open for this but since LibreOffice is developed mostly in C++ there isn't much Maven awareness: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=62353 hope future people will one day find this ticket resolved!